# How to display 0 when no FLI matching the query, but lease is there

Tags: sql, db2

say, we have two tables.

Table 1 with Lease and Table 2 with Amounts

Table Leases

`+----------+------------+
| Lease ID | Status     |
+----------+------------+
| 001      | Active     |
+----------+------------+
| 002      | Active     |
+----------+------------+
| 003      | Not Active |
+----------+------------+
| 004      | Active     |
+----------+------------+`

Table Amount

`+---------+--------+---------+
| Period  | Amount | LeaseID |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 2019-01 | 100    | 001     |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 2019-02 | 200    | 001     |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 2019-01 | 300    | 002     |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 2019-02 | 400    | 002     |
+---------+--------+---------+`

Query period = 2019-02. It must show only active leases in the following format :

Expected output

`+----------+--------+
| Lease ID | Amount |
+----------+--------+
| 001      | 200    |
+----------+--------+
| 002      | 400    |
+----------+--------+
| 004      | 0      |
+----------+--------+`

But, am getting like :

`+----------+--------+
| Lease ID | Amount |
+----------+--------+
| 001      | 200    |
+----------+--------+
| 002      | 400    |
+----------+--------+`

How to display as 0 for lease ID with NULL Amount record for the query period.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Don't add tags for products not involved. Are you using MySQL, DB2 or Oracle?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Are you using DB2 or Oracle?

Comment: What query returns these rows? Can you share it?

Comment: am using DB2 @jarlh

Comment: The below query returns these results @jarlh : ' select l.leaseid, a.amount
from lease l left join
     amount a
     on a.leaseid = l.leaseid
where l.status = 'active' and a.period = '2019-02'; '

Comment: You need to move the a.period condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Upon using ON instead of WHERE, it seems to be working. Thanks @jarlh

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join` :

```
select l.leaseid, coalesce(a.amount, 0)
from lease l left join
     amount a
     on a.leaseid = l.leaseid and a.period = '2019-02'
where l.status = 'active';
```

Comment: Switch to `'Active'`... (Seems like your column is case sensitive.)

Comment: @Yogesh Sharma : Thanks for the answer, it is working.